# App dev - Storing Shopify data in local DB

Tags: api, shopify, shopify-app

Is it normal for Shopify apps to store some or all data they need for their app in their local database and only fetch data via the Shopify API when the client logs in to update the data?

I know this has a lot of scenarios possible depending on the type of app.

Is anyone willing to share their experience and pros/cons of storing data locally vs accessing it via Shopify at all times?

Comment: I store data in the App when it is crazy not to. For example, I have an App that has to process many thousands of orders at one time, parsing the cart attributes for special fulfillment information. It would take way too long to always have to query the API for the right orders, and to then process these orders, again using the API. That task, even when optimized is slow.

Comment: I agree with David. It's costly to page through orders, or users, or products. Your better off syncing that kind of information to a local DB, then doing look ups from shopify when you need specific data.

Comment: @Luckner – if you’re happy with the answer, please mark it as accepted or follow up some more if you need more detail.

Comment: This is a really update to this question but thanks @David Lazar for the answer

Answer (score 6):

This is Edward, Shopify’s Lead Developer Advocate.

I wholeheartedly recommend you doing this, especially if you’re going to do any kind of calculations or processing on the data. Pulling the data down just-in-time is likely going to make for a pretty laggy experience.